# Unable to edit a table element after having just added column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I just added a new "imgurl" column by the following migration:

```
rails generate migration add_imgurl_to_users imgurl:string
```

and when I check my rails console, this is what I see for user 1:

```
irb(main):002:0> a = User.find_by(id: 1)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  => #<User id: 1, name: "iscprz", email: "fakeemail2@gmail.com", created_at: "2014-11-04 02:18:15", updated_at: "2014-11-04 02:45:33", password_digest: "$2a$10$UvHGZPAxQdCrsbOEyJeLPOuzXm7aJLYWJNKRnkJ5NkA...", imgurl: nil>
```

Whenever I make a new user, I get to my new.html.erb file inside the users view:

```
<h1>New user</h1>

<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %> </br>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %></br>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %> </br>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></br>

      <%= f.label :imgurl, "Background image URL" %>
      <%= f.text_field :imgurl %> </br>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

but at the screen, I enter text into the imgurl field and it doesn't save it to the database upon submitting the form...(the imgurl field is always nil after I check in rails console).

What step have I forgotten to take after having created the new imgurl column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, ...)` in your controller?